# Keyboard selection doesn't generate range object

Tags: javascript, keyboard, range, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I am currently trying to create an annotation tool that is also usable for blind users with a screen reader like JAWS. My tool is web-based so I can manipulate the DOM with JavaScript. The user is supposed to use a simple text selection in order to determine the text snippet he desires to be annotated.

JAWS clearly allows text selection but it executes this through keyboard shortcuts. As a result it doesn't seem to create the DOM range object which I wanted to use. It works perfectly fine when I select the text by mouse though.

I wonder if anyone knows how I could stabalize this behaviour in order to permanently get the correct range as I'm fairly new to including the use of screen readers. I hope you understand that I'm unsure what code snippets would help as the problem seems quiet general so feel free to ask for more details.

Would really appreciate any advice!

Comment: If you only observe this behavior with Jaws and not NVDA, try this: open quick settings (Insert+V), go to virtual cursor, selection and copy, and make sure that  the option is set on "highlighted text" and not "from virtual cursor". Tell me if it solved your problem, so that I can upgrade this comment into a real answer.

Comment: @QuentinC thanks for your answer but this didn't solve my issue. I reckon it is maybe not wanted by design that a range object is generated by keyboard?

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference between mouse and keyboard. Have you tried with NVDA ? Is the selection visible on the screen ? Is your zone contenteditable ? Maybe you can also have a look at browser settings

Comment: Could you share some code and produce a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please? It might be interesting to see how you are obtaining the range.

Comment: Hi, i have found a workaround with window.getSelection() as I figured I can collect the other relevant informations elsewhere. However if you would like to find an answer to this, it's the Thorium Reader for EPUBs (https://github.com/edrlab/thorium-reader). Thats why I would struggle to find the important code parts since everything is very distributed. Thank you nevertheless for your efforts.

Comment: @QuentinC I'd encourage you to upgrade your first comment into an answer, because it might help other people, at least it was a new detail in JAWS for me personally.